# WPF - Exporting DataGrid to Excel, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel alternative for Office 2019

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, datagrid, office-interop

I am trying to export my DataGrid to Excel (Office 2019/365).
My method is using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` extension, but it throws an exception, and I learned it will only work for Office 2013.

**So my question is**, are there any extensions that will work for Office 2019 that are interchangeable with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`? Would be great to have as little refactoring as possible.

My method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace My.NameSpace {

    class ExcelExport {

        public static void ExportDataGrid(object sender) {

            DataGrid currentGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            if (currentGrid != null) {

                StringBuilder sbGridData = new StringBuilder();
                List<string> listColumns = new List<string>();

                List<DataGridColumn> listVisibleDataGridColumns = new List<DataGridColumn>();

                List<string> listHeaders = new List<string>();

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = null;
                Workbook workbook = null;
                Worksheet worksheet = null;

                int rowCount = 1;
                int colCount = 1;

                try {

                    application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    workbook = application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                    worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

                    if (currentGrid.HeadersVisibility == DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column || currentGrid.HeadersVisibility == DataGridHeadersVisibility.All) {

                        foreach (DataGridColumn dataGridColumn in currentGrid.Columns.Where(dataGridColumn => dataGridColumn.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)) {

                            listVisibleDataGridColumns.Add(dataGridColumn);
                            if (dataGridColumn.Header != null) {

                                listHeaders.Add(dataGridColumn.Header.ToString());
                            }

                            worksheet.Cells[rowCount, colCount] = dataGridColumn.Header;
                            colCount++;
                        }

                        // IEnumerable collection = currentGrid.ItemsSource

                        foreach (object data in currentGrid.ItemsSource) {

                            listColumns.Clear();
                            colCount = 1;
                            rowCount++;

                            foreach (DataGridColumn dataGridColumn in listVisibleDataGridColumns) {

                                string strValue = string.Empty;
                                Binding objBinding = null;
                                DataGridBoundColumn dataGridBoundColumn = dataGridColumn as DataGridBoundColumn;

                                if (dataGridBoundColumn != null) {

                                    objBinding = dataGridBoundColumn.Binding as Binding;
                                }

                                DataGridTemplateColumn dataGridTemplateColumn = dataGridColumn as DataGridTemplateColumn;

                                if (dataGridTemplateColumn != null) {

                                    // this is a template column, let's see the underlying dependency object
                                    DependencyObject dependencyObject = dataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate.LoadContent();

                                    FrameworkElement frameworkElement = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;

                                    if (frameworkElement == null) {

                                        FieldInfo fieldInfo = frameworkElement.GetType().GetField("ContentProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
                                        
                                        if (fieldInfo == null) {

                                            if (frameworkElement is System.Windows.Controls.TextBox || frameworkElement is TextBlock || frameworkElement is ComboBox) {

                                                fieldInfo = frameworkElement.GetType().GetField("TextProeprty");

                                            } else if (frameworkElement is DatePicker) {

                                                fieldInfo = frameworkElement.GetType().GetField("SelectedDateProperty");
                                            }
                                        }

                                        if (fieldInfo != null) {

                                            DependencyProperty dependencyProperty = fieldInfo.GetValue(null) as DependencyProperty;
                                            if (dependencyProperty != null) {

                                                BindingExpression bindingExpression = frameworkElement.GetBindingExpression(dependencyProperty);
                                                if (bindingExpression != null) {

                                                    objBinding = bindingExpression.ParentBinding;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (objBinding != null) {

                                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objBinding.Path.Path)) {

                                        PropertyInfo pi = data.GetType().GetProperty(objBinding.Path.Path);

                                        if (pi != null) {

                                            object propValue = pi.GetValue(data, null);

                                            if (propValue != null) {

                                                strValue = Convert.ToString(propValue);

                                            } else {

                                                strValue = string.Empty;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    if (objBinding.Converter != null) {

                                        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue)) {

                                            strValue = objBinding.Converter.Convert(strValue, typeof(string), objBinding.ConverterParameter, objBinding.ConverterCulture).ToString();

                                        } else {

                                            strValue = objBinding.Converter.Convert(data, typeof(string), objBinding.ConverterParameter, objBinding.ConverterCulture).ToString();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                listColumns.Add(strValue);

                                worksheet.Cells[rowCount, colCount] = strValue;

                                colCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException) {

                } finally {

                    workbook.Close();
                    application.Quit();
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've recently been moving my apps over to use [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml). You can add it as a Nuget to your project and the Github repo for it should have pretty decent documentation on how to get started!

Comment: @mm8, I was using 15.0.4795.1000 (latest stable version). In retrospect, I should've seen that it said right there in the description that it was only for Office 2013.

Comment: @Jaskier, thank you for the tip -- I will look into that!

Comment: @OleM: Try to add a reference to `Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library` under the `COM` tab in the reference manager in Visual Studio.

Comment: @mm8, thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately, the issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

It may not have the same api but EPPlus is a good option for creating excel files from c#.

It doesn't use the interop libraries so its not dependant on the version of Office installed(office is not needed at all).

Version [4.5.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/4.5.3.3) is the last version using a LGPL licence, later versions have a dual licence, which is chargeable for commercial use.

Comment: thanks for the tip, will look into that and get back to you!